# EWS throw an exception in Autodiscover method

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect with email box by EWS. And after that line:

```
 service1.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAdress);
```

this code throw error

> Message = "The Autodiscover service returned an error"
>
> InnerException = " "
>
> TargetSite = "Boolean TryLastChanceHostRedirection[TSettings] 
>   (System.String, System.Uri, TSettings ByRef)"
>
> HelpLink = ""

This code is working for another email box on other domain.

I think that something is wrong with Exchange serwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Autodiscover service is providing a redirection. Try adding this [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635285(v=exchg.80).aspx) as the second argument in the Autodiscover URL method:

```
static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
{
    // Return true if the URL is an HTTPS URL.
    return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
}
```